# establishing c3p0 connection pool with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am supposed to store large amount of pdf files in database MySQL. I have used c3p0 connection pooling with MySQL. Configured as below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory> 

   <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property> 
   <property name="connection.username">root</property> 
   <property name="connection.password">root</property> 
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
                      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">300</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">10</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">600</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1200</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">600</property>
   <property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property>
   <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>

   <!-- property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"> 4 </property-->

   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 

   <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>   

   <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
   <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property> 

   <property name="show_sql">true</property> 

   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 


   <mapping class="com.pojo.PDFDetails"/>

  </session-factory> 
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

After importing 6  or sometimes 7 pdfs i am encountering below exception:

```
--[001_KL695627797FT.pdf, 002_KL695627655FT.pdf, 003_KL695627505FT.pdf, 004_MN574152846FT.pdf, 005_SE082789582FT.pdf, 006_KL848699892FT.pdf]---
G:\Phase II Scanning\ABX1185 to ABX1260\ABX1185\ABN4737\006_KL848699892FT.pdf 006_KL848699892FT.pdf
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.pojo.HibUtil.storeInDb(HibUtil.java:32)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.callList(MonitorPdf.java:97)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.callList(MonitorPdf.java:84)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.callList(MonitorPdf.java:84)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.callList(MonitorPdf.java:84)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.cleanPDFDir(MonitorPdf.java:31)
    at monitor.MonitorPdf.main(MonitorPdf.java:14)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 14 more
```

My c3p0 jar version is 0.9.1.2 
Can someone help me out? Please avoid wild guesses.

Comment: When are you committing your connecting?

Comment: i am commiting after every pdf insertion , i know its a bad piece but we need to assure that all the pdfs are stored  and exception is handled accordingly ( in case of duplicacy)  so that the execution is carried ahead for next pdf.

Comment: This might help http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/25350-problem-with-c3p0

Comment: After going through BasicResourcePool class, only thing that can be said with the information and logs provided above is that an acquire request was forcefully killed before the timeout. But since you haven't set the timeout, it means this acquire was on the queue for fairly long time and then the source for the resources went down. [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1/com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool.java) check awaitAvailable method.